# В каких случаях использовать ThreadLocal context?

Tags: java, android, многопоточность, context

Студия предлагает использовать private final ThreadLocal context = new ThreadLocal(); вместо private Context context; Это может предотвратить утечку памяти?

```
public class FetchEditTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Pic> {

private Pic picResult = new Pic();
private final ThreadLocal<Context> context = new ThreadLocal<Context>();
private AsyncResponse output;
private int index;

public FetchEditTask(Context context, AsyncResponse output, int index) {
    this.context.set(context);
    this.output = output;
    this.index = index;
}

@Override
protected Pic doInBackground(Void... params) {

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(context.get().getResources().getString(R.string.pixabay_api_link))
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    ApiService client = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);
    Call<Pic> call;
    call = client.getEditorPic(index);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Pic>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Pic> call, Response<Pic> response) {
            try {
                if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.d(context.get().getResources().getString(R.string.No_Success), response.errorBody().string());
                } else {
                    picResult = response.body();
                    if (picResult != null) {
                        output.processFinish(picResult);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Pic> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context.get(), context.get().getResources().getString(R.string.wrong_message), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    });
    return picResult;
}
}
```

Comment: Не знаю как там в андроиде. Но треад локал  - уникальная переменная, которая принадлежит одному потоку. То есть ты можешь быть уверен, что ее из других потоков никто не сможет изменить. Самая потокобезопасная переменная.

Comment: Ничего не получится. В `doInBackground` получите `NullPointerException`, поскольку значение этой переменной будет существовать только в главном потоке, где Вы его присвоили. Разве ретрофит выполняет запрос не асинхронно, зачем Вы его в `AsyncTask` загнали?

Comment: ок буду переделывать